# Text editor that mimics the same hotkeys as those found in JetBrains WebStorm, IntelliJ, PyCharm etc

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, text-editor, jetbrains-ide

I would love to just replicate the same hot keys as I'm used to in WebStorm and IntelliJ, Android Studio, but just in a text editor.

Anyone knows if there is a project open source or not for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for both Atom and Sublime. You'll have to change the default keybindings for either editor but this is easy to do.

For Atom [here](https://atom.io/packages/intellij-idea-keymap) is a link that will show you how to change the default keybindings to intellij.

For Sublime, [this link](https://gist.github.com/nelanka/2e72b2ffa8fca1b2b799) contains the intellij keybindings.

If you want to use another IDE's keybindings besides intellij, just google `sublime <IDE that you want> keybinding map`.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Visual Studio Code. It's a great editor with loads of available extensions. You'll be able to [configure the key bindings yourself](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) or install something like [IntelliJ IDEA Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/k--kato/vscode-intellij-idea-keybindings).